# Hosting an MVC and a webforms site on the same IIS7 instance - web.config inheritance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, hosting, webforms

We have a website that was written in classic ASP, then I started to extend it using web forms.  These extensions exist in a subfolder of the main folder.  Now we've decided we'd prefer to use MVC3.  Also, as we'd like to convert all our site to MVC3 over time, we are hosting the MVC code in the application root.  I've found some other questions where people have a similar issue to mine, but no solution.  The issue is simply that my web forms app can't seem to be stopped from inheriting the web.config settings from the root folder, and as a result, it won't run, it either complains about missing dlls, or complains about running the wrong version of .NET, or complains I need to remove some settings ( which I try and can never get to work right ).  The app in the subfolder is also hosting a webservice that is called by our application, and it also runs HTTP handlers to protect our imaging content, so it's got a bit of stuff in it.  Do I need to run my MVC site in a subfolder ? Is there any way to have MVC in the folder above a web forms app ? I'd prefer to set things up so they share session data, but that's looking likely to be impossible at this stage...

So to be clear the folder structure is:

```
<root>
   contains asp site and MVC site.
   <subfolder>
      contains webforms application
   </subfolder>
</root>
```

and my issue is getting the subfolder to run, preferably in the same session as the MVC app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you can't run regular .aspx files on an MVC site. You are correct though, web.config settings are inherited from the parent (chain), but you just add a new web.config in your directory with relevant settings.

What you will have to do is play with the routes, because by default MVC will route all requests into your controller classes. But if you google around its fairly simple to add an exception to the routing.

If you post some of the specific errors we can probably help further.

Oh and do you mean Classic ASP? i.e. not Classic ASP.NET? Because you'll have fun sharing session data between ASP & ASP.NET.

Comment: Yes, we use the database to get the data between ASP.NET and asp.  It's making sure the session stays the same between web forms and MVC that is my concern.  Routing is not my problem, I can load an aspx in the root, but I can't load anything from the app in the subfolder.

Comment: Routing will almost certainly be part of the problem, because it routes sub-folders to controllers - which you have to stop. That said if you can give details of the exact errors we can help more.

Comment: Well, I'll need to spend some time making web.config changes in order to get you the whole gamut of different errors I am getting, but they boil down to 'duplicate web.config section not allowed' and 'cannot load dll because your site is running on an older version of .NET'.  My solution would be to be able to run this app so it did not inherit the settings from the root folder.  I don't think any code change that does not do that, will solve any of my specific error messages.

Comment: Web.config is always inherited - that's normally one of the great things about it. But that said you should be able to resolve them all. Remove the duplicate sections, and make sure all aspects of the site are using the same version of .net

Comment: OK - if that's the general solution, how do I get my webforms app to use the same version of .NET as the MVC site ? Because that seems to be the core issue, I got to the point of getting rid of duplicate errors, only to be told it could not load the dlls it needed to for MVC ( despite their not being in use ) because the DLLs were too new.

Comment: The version of .net being used is set in IIS.